# serverless websockets: how to persist execution environment throughout ws connection

Tags: node.js, websocket, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Following the example on the official docs: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/websocket, I noticed that the execution environment for the message handler is not kept persistent over the lifetime of the ws connection.

Here is my default handler:

```
let a = null;

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log(a);
  a = "hello";
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: "message received" }),
  };
};
```

Sending a message several times over websocket always prints `a` as null as the variable is not kept persistent. How to ensure that the execution environment remains persistent over the lifetime of the ws connection?

For some context:

What I'm trying to achieve is real-time audio transcription over websockets using [Google Cloud Speech](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/speech/latest). This requires the [speech recognizer class](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/speech/latest/speech/v1.speechclient-class) instance to persist over multiple ws messages where each message receives a packet of audio data.

Comment: Isn't a serverless implementation going to be stateless on the server so `a` will not be persisted.  Isn't that what "serverless" means?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with only Lambda and API Gateway connected via a websocket integration.

In this context API Gateway is responsible for holding the websocket connection, the Lambda function handler runs once in response to a websocket message and then exits.

If you want to maintain state between Lambda function invocations, you'll need to persist it externally, using something like DynamoDB or S3 - although Step Functions might be a good choice for your use case.

As your example should demonstrate - it's possible to memoize a variable outside of the handler between *serial* Lambda invocations to the same container (this is a popular way to re-use a database connection between invocations). But there's no guarantee that a user will be routed to the same Lambda container over the course of multiple serial invocations.